# How to get specific currency symbol(rupee symbol in my case) in angular js instead of the default one (dollar $ symbol)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

When i use 'currency' in angular js, I am getting a dollar symbol. How to get required currency symbols based on the requirements. As if now i need to know how to display a rupee symbol using currency. It will be of great use if anyone could explain how to make use of this currency for different symbols at the times of different requirements.

sample :

```
Item Price<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{item.price | currency}}</span>
```

If my item.price is 200. Here it shows 200$. I need to display rupee symbol instead of dollar.

Comment: This is a better solution
:D
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547680/angular-js-currency-symbol-euro-after#34953870

Answer (score 68, accepted):

To display currency symbol in angular js you need provide HTML entity for currency symbols below are the examples and usage in through code and in template :

Inside your Template example of Euro:

```
Item Price<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{price | currency:"&euro;"}}</span>
```

example of Rupee:

```
Item Price<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{price | currency:"&#8377;"}}</span>
```

Also check below url

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/euro.html

From controller :

Inject $filter in your controller

```
$scope.price=$filter('currency')($scope.price,'&euro;')
```

Comment: @Ebenezar I thought you needed to show rupee symbol not euro.

Comment: @Foreever Yes i needed rupee symbol. As you can see from the answers i have not recieved the exact solution. By this one atleast i learned how to make use of different currency symbols by trying with euro. Still waiting for rupee though !

Comment: @Ebenezar See my answer then. Tested it as well.

Comment: @JQuery Guru I am new to angular and also read the currency doc for angular but i am unable to understand which of the two option(i.e. "In HTML Template Binding" , "In Javascript" ) is used i have tried for both but only one is working HTML one but i want the same from javascript

Answer (score 6):

You can use the symbol parameter:

```
Item Price<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{item.price | currency[:symbol]}}</span>
```

Exemple:

```
Item Price<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{item.price | currency:"USD$"}}</span>
```

Please refer to this:

```
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:currency
```

Comment: Try as follow:
currency:[&euro;]
If the € sign does not appear on your example, it's probably due to your file encoding.

Answer (score 5):

I'm late to the party but worked on this filter for my last project.

if you have the ISO 4217 currency code (3 chars length e.g. USD, EUR, etc) isoCurrency can output the right **format**, **fraction size** and **symbol**.

```
// in controller
$scope.amount = 50.50;
$scope.currency = 'USD';

// in template
{{ amount | isoCurrency:currency }} // $50.50
```

- [isoCurrency](https://github.com/zwacky/isoCurrency)
- [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nqf0ye00/55/)

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution giving for the INR currency.

If you want to **display symbol**

```
Item Price<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{item.price | currency:'INR'}}</span>
```

or

```
Item Price<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{item.price | currency:'INR':'symbol'}}</span>
```

or

```
Item Price<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{item.price | currency:'INR':'symbol-narrow'}}</span>
```

> Result will look like: **₹140.00**

Or 
If you want to **display code** instead of symbol then use following

```
 Item Price<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{item.price | currency:'INR':'code'}}</span>
```

> Result will look like : **INR140.00**

Similarly you can check for the code of the other countries and replace that instead of INR(India Code)

Answer (score 3):

The currency symbol can be changed from the default $ symbol to something else as follows:

In HTML Template Binding

```
 {{ currency_expression | currency[:symbol] }}
```

In JavaScript

```
 $filter('currency')(amount[, symbol])
```

We can display rupee symbol(in this case) for example as follows:

In HTML Template Binding

```
Item Price<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{price | currency:"&#8377;"}}</span>
```

OR

In JavaScript

```
$scope.price=$filter('currency')($scope.price,"&#8377;")
```

Also, we can add a text rather than a symbol if needed as follows:

```
Item Price<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{price | currency:"rupee"}}</span>
```

*Note: Copying rupee symbol directly into HTML will not work.*

See  [AngularJS currency documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:currency)

Answer (score 3):

$ is the default symbol for angular currency filter. To get the result in other symbol, for example Rupee (₹), you must explicitly define it in your app.
For displaying ₹ symbol you just have to add an option in currency.

Example:

> `<span> <b>{{i.price | currency : '&#8377;' }}</b> </span>`

`&#8377;` is the HTML code for ₹ symbol.

Answer (score 3):

```
<h2>{{8.99 | currency:'INR':true}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to make it dynamic, here is my solution:

HTML

```
<div>{{ 100 | currencySymbol: 'USD' }}</div>
```

Filter

```
angular.filter('currencySymbol', function ($filter) {
    return function(amount, currency) {
        return $filter('currency')(amount, currency_symbols[currency]);
    }
});
```

Javascript currency array

```
var currency_symbols = {
    'USD': '$', // US Dollar
    'EUR': '€', // Euro
    'GBP': '£', // British Pound Sterling
    'ILS': '₪', // Israeli New Sheqel
    'INR': '₹', // Indian Rupee
    'JPY': '¥', // Japanese Yen
    'KRW': '₩', // South Korean Won
    'NGN': '₦', // Nigerian Naira
    'PHP': '₱', // Philippine Peso
    'PLN': 'zł', // Polish Zloty
    'PYG': '₲', // Paraguayan Guarani
    'THB': '฿', // Thai Baht
    'UAH': '₴', // Ukrainian Hryvnia
    'VND': '₫', // Vietnamese Dong
};
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Angular JS docs [Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) the currency can be changed

```
Item Price<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{price | currency:[symbol]}}</span>
Item Price in Dollar<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{price | currency:"USD$"}}</span>
Item Price in Euro<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{price | currency:"&euro;"}}</span>
```

And for INR it will be character code [Link2](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/latin1/3.html#A2)

```
Item Price in Ruppese<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{price | currency:"&#8377;"}}</span>
```

`"&#8377;"` is the character code of :"₹"

Comment: For more visit this [link](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/devanagarichart.html)

Answer (score 1):

See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:currency

Simple with:

```
currency:"USD$"
```

and instead of USD$ use what ever you want

Answer (score 0):

Currency pipe has 3 parameters

> 1. Desire currency code.
>
> .
>
> 2. A Boolean value to indicate whether to display the currency symbol.
>
> .
>
> 3. Digit info(has 3 parts): consist of minimum number of integer digit, minimum number of fractional digit and maximum number of fractional digit.

```
<span>{{value| currency:'1':2:'3'}}</span>
```

Example

```
<span>{{9.667| currency:'USD':true:'2.2-3'}}</span>
```

**Output**

$09.667

Refer for more details: https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

For currency code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217

If you want to show the currency in Indian rupee. use code `INR`

```
<span>{{100| currency:'INR':true}}</span>
```

**Output**

₹100.00