# unable to insert html code inside filter?

Tags: html, angularjs

**Angualr JS code:**

```
$scope.rupee = $filter('currency')($scope.dols * 67.33, 'INR', 3);
```

I am trying to insert html code inside this filter. That is instead of 'INR', I wish to get ₹ symbol. Please help me to solve this. And the problem is not getting the ₹ through filter. Instead of 'INR', I want to use &#8377 but it's not rendering as I expected.

**html code:**

```
<div>{{rupee}}</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML code for INR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430242/html-code-for-inr)

Comment: I want to get the symbol from $filter. If I use &#8377 in filter instead of 'INR', It's not working. Also it wouldn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your statement to

```
$scope.rupee = $filter('currency')($scope.dols * 67.33, '\u20B9', 3);
```

---

As you asked, "Can we write HTML code inside symbolFormat parameter?"
Answer will be below:

[image: Currency Filter function]
[image: Number Formats]

**It takes a string parameter, so whatever string you are providing, it will be used to apply as currency symbol**

[For reference you can check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/y7r1xe0t/305/)

Comment: Thank you. :D :D ... It's working..... Can we write html inside filter?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

> {{ currency_expression | currency : symbol : fractionSize}}

```
$scope.rupee = $filter('currency')($scope.dols * 67.33, '₹', 3);
```

See all use cases (currency symbol & sign - in controller & directly on view):

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="RupeeCtrl">
    <b>From controller with sign</b><br/>
    {{rupeeSign}}
    <br/><br/>
    <b>From controller with code</b><br/>
    {{rupeeCode}}
    <br/><br/>
    <b>From view</b><br/>
    {{ price | currency:'&#8377;'}}      
</div>

function RupeeCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.price = 75.255;
    $scope.rupeeSign = $filter('currency')($scope.price, '₹', 3);
    $scope.rupeeCode = $filter('currency')($scope.price, '\u20B9', 3);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seqsyndw/3/)

Mixed with answer from @Romesh Jain

Comment: If I copy the symbol, it works fine. But If there is no way to get symbol by html inside filter, Why to mention an argument 'symbol' in the 'currency' filter?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate question to this: [How to get specific currency symbol(rupee symbol in my case) in angular js instead of the default one (dollar $ symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612212/how-to-get-specific-currency-symbolrupee-symbol-in-my-case-in-angular-js-inste)

Just use this ASCII code for the Rupee symbol: ₹

See the ASCII code here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm

Comment: No. not at all. I just want to get it through the html code inside a filter

Comment: well why can't you use the accepted answer from the link above and do something like this: `<div>{{rupeeAmount | currency:"&#8377;"}}</div>`. Why do you have to set it in the code?

Comment: This is my task to accomplish for today. Can we write html code inside filter?

Comment: If there is no way to get symbol by html inside filter, Why to mention an argument 'symbol' in the 'currency' filter?