# Angularjs bind HTML currency codes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to filter and display HTML currency [codes](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/currency/).

So my function gets the code name and returns the HTML code that match:

```
            vm.filterCurrencyCode = function(currncey){
                console.log(currncey);
                if( currncey ===  ''|| angular.isUndefined(currncey)){
                    return '&#8362'; // default
                }
                else if(currncey == 'USD' || currncey == 'CAD'){
                    return '&#036;'; //usd
                }
                else if(currncey == 'GBP' || currncey == 'GBp'){
                    return '&#163;'; //gbp
                }else{
                    return currncey; //return name
                }
            }
```

And in my HTML:

```
<td data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{$index}}">{{vm.filterCurrencyCode(nia.CurrencyCode)}}</td>
```

But instead of the matching HTML symbol, the page display's the string - `'&#8362'`.

Comment: Maybe something you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696619/displaying-unicode-symbols-in-html

Comment: I have already have Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to bind `HTML` to your view, which is by default not allowed. To achieve this you need sanitize your input using `sanitize.js`. Make sure you include  `sanitize.js` in your project.

Once done, you need in include `ngSanitize` module in your app like following code

`angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);`

And insted of using `{{}}` you need to use  `ng-bind-html` to bind the scope object to your view.

Your HTML code should look like following example

```
<td data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{$index}}" 
    ng-bind-html="vm.filterCurrencyCode(nia.CurrencyCode)"></td>
```

You can get more details on this [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) and [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)

Comment: Testing and posting the result.

Comment: @PSK Your approach is correct, but in my opinion, using currency filter is more better bcoz this way, he is future proof. Any new currency code comes in, it will work directly. With above approach, he needs to keep adding conditions in his controller for more returning proper code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the currency filter to do this.

Read about it here: [Currency filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)

Refer the SO answer: [How to get specific currency symbol(rupee symbol in my case) in angular js instead of the default one (dollar $ symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612212/how-to-get-specific-currency-symbolrupee-symbol-in-my-case-in-angular-js-inste)

Comment: Testing and posting the result.

Comment: You should use this approach to be future proof